# innerHTML of null error

Tags: javascript

Using `console.log` I am able to see value coming from another page, but when I am placing this value using `document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = xyz.age;` it's giving me error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

My JS

```
xyz = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("details"));
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = xyz.age; //getting error from here
console.log(xyz.age);
```

Can you guyz help me out

Comment: Are you executing it after page load completes? If not, checkout [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: The error means that there is no element in the DOM with an `id="abc"`. Try to do a `console.log(document.getElementbyId('abc')` and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Is your script running before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @ArupRakshit your comment worked

Comment: @Jason is my answer correct?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Yes

Comment: @Jason Great, can you accept the answer?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda You are not sure if your answer is correct or not?

Comment: Just trying to get OP to accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

This example works using your code, you might be executing the script before the dom has been fully loaded? Try wrapping your code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code...
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  xyz = { age: 24 }; // Mock data from localstorage
  document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = xyz.age;
  console.log(xyz.age);
});
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Comment: Or, better yet, just move the `script` to just prior to the closing `body` tag. It's more efficient than registering an event handler.

Comment: @ScottMarcus agreed, no idea of OPs setup though.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not xyz, it's with document.getElementById('abc'). 'abc' cannot be found when your script is executing, either the element is not there, or the script is running before the document is ready.

If the latter, you may need to execute the script in a callback function after the document has been loaded. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp